# How to specify importance of html elements?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, html5

Is it possible to specify what elements of the page are important, or, more specifically, what elements of the page **are not important**?

I'm using HTML5 new elements (nav, header, footer, section, article, aside...), but there is sometimes my login form (in the header of my page though) in the Google description of my website pages...

Is there a solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: There's a method in Google Appliance to comment content out with `<!--googleoff: index--> your html <!--googleon: index>` but that doesn't work with Google bot.

Comment: Ok, I will use micro format data to try to improve the way google indexes my web pages, I hope it will be enough.

Comment: If google decides to show the login form, it means the META description is not good enough, and that the page lacks good main content. Does it happens in pages with low content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's shown in Google's search snippet description of your site is determined partly by what's in your meta description, and partly by what Google deems most relevant from the page to the a given search query.

If a meta description is **too short**, **too long**, or just **not very descriptive**, there seems to be a greater chance that Google will ignore it.

The general rules of thumb for optimising meta descriptions are well documented so I won't repeat them here, but following these guidelines will give you the greatest chance of ensuring that Google shows them.

Comment: Yes, the problem is which parts Google deems to be most relevant... Sometimes it appears that Google finds relevant the login form... The website may be bad code, I didn't do it...

Comment: What is relevant will depend on the search terms used. On the occasions you see the login form text in your result snippet, what search terms did you use?